# Problema con onLoad cargando multiples archivos

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Estoy intentado cargar varias imagenes (una por una) y me gustaría usar un vector para no tener que manejar un evento onLoad para cada imagen.

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

Primero hago un vector con los ID de cada imagen:

```
    for(var i=0;i<=n_imagenes;i++)
    img_id[i] = "img_"+i;
```

Luego hago un append y las agrago a la página:

```
    for(var i=0;i<=n_imagenes;i++)
    txt +=  '<div><img id="' + img_id[i] + '"></div>';
    $("#padre").append(txt);
```

Luego intento cargar 10 archivos:

```
count1=0;
count2=0;
class LoadImages
{
  constructor()
  {

       //Esto funciona siempre
       $("#file").change(function(e) 
       {     
         img = e.target.files[0];
         img.src = url.createObjectURL(img);
         $("#"+img_id[count1]).attr("src",img.src);
         $("#file").val("");  
         count1++;       
       }


       //Esto solo funciona una vez
       $("#"+img_id[count2]).on("load", function(e) 
       {
          count2++;  

       });

   }
}
```

El problema es que "onLoad" solo me funciona una vez cuando (count2=0). Es decir todas las imagenes se cargan pero solo se entra una vez en el evento onLoad. O lo que es lo mismo count1 alcaza el valor 10 y count2 solo llega hasta valor 1.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo o una forma mejor de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, encontré la solución... aquí la dejo por si le ayuda a alguien.

```
 for(var i=0;i<n_imagenes;i++)
 {
   $("#"+img_id[i]).on("load", function(e) 
   {


   });
 }
```